# How do I set action to alert view button (not so simple as that)

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, push, uialertview

I am already trying it through the delegate method clickedButtonAtIndex: but I need to push a view through navigation controller as soon as the user presses "ok"...

I can't allocate the view inside the method, Xcode doesn't recognize the view controller's name in the code. Any idea what I'm coin wrong?

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex { 
    switch(buttonIndex) {
        case 0:


             ReminderCompleted *view = [[ReminderCompleted alloc]initWithNibName:@"ReminderCompleted" bundle:nil];

             [view.navigationController pushViewController:view animated:NO];



            break;
        case 1:
            //cancel
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
```

I get some errors

Comment: You'll have to push your new view to a navigation controller that is `already` visible on the screen. That one of the new view will surely not such one.

Comment: And what errors you are getting?

Comment: Expected expression/ use of undeclared identifier 'view'. Is there a specific way i should do it? I can't think of other way other than allocating a new view... What do you suggest?

Comment: Ah, a side note that came into my mind: if I remember well, you can't create local variables just in one branch of a switch-case. Or you have to create your ReminderCompelted pointer _before_ the switch (you can init it with null) or you have to place your code for case 0: in curly brackets something like `case 0: { ReminderView *view = ...; [view someMethod]; break; }`

Comment: I tried it both ways, and all possible position for the brackets lol... I'm trying this for like 3 hours, its the last detail of my app. Can you suggest anything else i could do?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

<del>You cannot push a view, you can only push view controllers. You should be able to structure the code in a similar fashion, but instantiate a view controller (which can also use a nib) instead, and pass that to the navigation controller's push method.</del>

Edit: Your variable name confused me, and you are indeed using a view controller. My suspect now is declaring a new variable inside of a switch, which Objective-C does not like. Try the same code, but declare the variable before the switch (you can leave it uninitialized until the right case happens).

```
ReminderCompleted *reminderVC;
switch(buttonIndex) {
  case 0:
    reminderVC = [[ReminderCompleted alloc]initWithNibName:@"ReminderCompleted" bundle:nil];
    [view.navigationController pushViewController:view animated:NO];
    break;
```

Comment: That worked, Thank you very much! I just have one more little problem. The alert comes from the appDelegate, so "view.navigationControler push..."  won't work because i'm not in a specific view. Any suggestion on how to do this?

Comment: I would restructure the app to not fuss much with this stuff in the app delegate. Hard to say what the best way to do that is in your case, but the app delegate should be as hands-off as possible with regard to your app's workflow.

Comment: It's a kind of robbing my answer from the comment, isn't it?

Comment: That's not what happened on my end; but I acknowledge the frustration. I will find some of your good answers elsewhere and up vote, you deserve it. Please share that stuff in answer format when it is likely to be the solution!